# Quick way to create debug build for visual studio projects

Tags: visual-c++

I have 15 projects in my Visual studio solution , I didn't create debug builds(was lazy) when I added these projects now I am in need of debug build. Is there a hack to get a debug build of my solution from the release build itself? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the build settings to debug and rebuild solution. 
VS creates automatically Debug and Release. 
If you have modified configuration (only for release) than there is no magic trick here - copy the default DEBUG configuration and change it as well.